# Why is my React Router selecting two Routes in a nested Switch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My App.js is as such:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/studio">
            <Studio />
          </Route>
          <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

& my Studio.js is as follows:

```js
const Studio = () => {
  let { path } = useRouteMatch()
  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path}>
          <Editor />
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/categories`}>Studio/Categories</Route>
        <Route component={NotFound} />
        {/* <Route exact path={`${path}/*`} component={NotFound} /> */}
      </Switch>
    </>
  )
}
```

It seems routing is working perfectly fine for App.js but for Studio.js, the Switch doesn't stop at the first match and is rendering `<NotFound/>` when visiting `/studio` as well as `/studio/categories`.

What can I do to make it work such that only one Route is rendered within the Switch which is the default behaviour as per the docs if I'm not wrong?

Reproducible SandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-nested-glled

Comment: Because you have to add [`exact`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#exact-bool).

Comment: Seems to work correctly: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-wiles-negnr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please create a reproducible codesandbox with the issue

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have import typo `BrowserRouter as Switch`, you just need to import regular `Switch` in Nested component

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Switch, // remove `BrowserRouter as` thing
  Route,
  useRouteMatch
} from "react-router-dom";
```